# Accessibility: paused or stumbled voice input to Google Assistant

Tags: google, accessibility, google-assistant

This post is an accessibility request to do with voice input to Google which is paused or stumbled.

When my five year old child uses the Google Assistant search box on the Google Assistant widget to search for something or ask Google to do something with their voice, my child speaks a bit slowly and with some stumbles and autocorrections, on behalf of my child, so, I was wondering, whether there is a way to configure the Google voice search in the settings so that slow (or corrected), input, even with longer pauses, even towards the end of speech, can be configured, in the settings (somehow).

When will support for this kind of variation in the voice input be catered for by Google?

Is there a way to configure this at present?

As an adult, I also, find myself, having to speak quickly, at times, in order for Google not to respond prematurely.

Thanks.